# FormGroup with initial value and validators are not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I created a form group in my ts file:

```
datenForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datenForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        beginDatum: ['29/03/2019', [Validators.required, this.checkMonth]],
        endDatum: ['29/03/2020', [Validators.required, this.checkSomething]],
        username: ['pedro', [Validators.required, this.checkName]],
      },
    );
  }
```

I created 3 value in my formsgroup and i wanna use a validator for each value so i created my 3 validators checkMonth, checkSomething, checkName.

I created my validators in my ts:

```
checkMonth(group: FormGroup) {
    console.log(group.get("beginndatum").value);
  }

checkSomething(group: FormGroup) {
    return false;
  }
```

Here I just want to try the validators (i will write the correct one when i know how it works).

In my html file I use it like that:

```
<datepicker
              (datepickerChanged)="changeInfo(beginDatum)"
              #beginDatumId="beginDatum"
              invalid="{{datenForm.get('beginDatum').invalid && datenForm.get('beginDatum').dirty}}"
              error=""
              name="beginDatum"
              value="{{datenForm.get('beginDatum').value}}">
</datepicker>
```

My issue are here, in the case i have an initial value in my formgroup then i have an error because group.get("beginndatum").value is undefinned in checkMonth so i did that:

```
checkMonth(group: FormGroup) {
    if (group.get("beginndatum") == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

But my checkValidator is not working, i can set return true or false it never put me an error.

How can i use the validators with an initial value and bind it with my component ?

Comment: if your add the validator to a FormControl, the argument is the own FormControl (NOT the formGroup). FutherMore, a custom validator must return **null**  (not false) if all is ok and an object or value if is invalid.

Comment: Thank you, can you also check my html because the validators has no effect....

Comment: I don't know about your `datepicker` component, but if is a custom formControl well-realized, you should use `formControlName="beginDatum"` or `[formControl]="`datenForm.get('beginDatum')". then you can forget the `(datepickerChanges)` and the `value`. Is is a datepicker in javascript, in the function  `(datepickerChanged)` you need use `this.datenForm.get('beginDatum').setValue(beginDatum.value)` or similar to give value to the formControl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) `group()` method expects a collection of child controls. So `beginDatum`, `endDatum` and `username` are all [FormControls](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl).
2. Your template file need to access these controls. Use `formControlName` input on each one of your form controls like this : `<datepicker formControlName="beginDatum">...` to make this happen.
3. `checkMonth()` and every one of your validation methods are expecting a `FormGroup` but they should be expecting a `FormControl` because this is what they're really receiving.

Btw I strongly suggest you to read some doc about [template-driven](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-2-forms-template-driven) and [reactive](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-2-forms-reactive) forms because you seem to mix them both a bit.